# Javascript lose focus on first invalid field (jQuery Validation) when labels 'display:block'

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, focus

Javascript lose focus on first invalid field on 'unhighlight' event (jQuery Validation) when error messages (labels) 'display:block'.

I use pure code from latest jQuery Validation: jquerycom/Plugins/Validation

```
body {padding:20px;}
/*label.error {display:block;}*/
label.error {color:red;}
p {padding-bottom:15px;}
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/352TH/3/

1. My error labels are 'inline' in css.
2. Push Submit button -> two errors are shown, focus on email field.
3. Write valid email into email field.
4. Push Submit button -> one error is shown, **focus** on comment field.

Now just uncommented `/*label.error { display:block; }*/` line in css code

```
body {padding:20px;}
label.error {display:block;}
label.error {color:red;}
p {padding-bottom:15px;}
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/352TH/4/

1. My error labels are 'display:block' in css.
2. Push Submit button -> two errors are shown, focus on email field.
3. Write valid email into email field.
4. Push Submit button -> one error is shown, **NO focus** on comment field.

:(

Comment: its working fine for me in Chrome

Comment: No, no, no, I use Chrome too. Did you push Run (jsFiddle) after uncommented css?

Comment: Following your steps to the letter (in Chrome 23.0.1271.97 m) for http://jsfiddle.net/352TH/3/, I am unable to reproduce this behavior. My cursor is faithfully blinking in the appropriate input waiting for me to type something else.

Comment: @DenisDerebizov - yes , I use jsFiddle all the time , it works as expected

Comment: I see the biggest problem is to explain properly. I created two link on jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/352TH/3/ and http://jsfiddle.net/352TH/4/). I also want to clarify that I can't get focus in http://jsfiddle.net/352TH/4/ case only after unhighlight event. To reproduce this jquery.validation bug you should pass through all 4 steps.

Comment: I get focus after 4 step if I push Submit twice, but if I push Submit once there is NO focus.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In your code you have:

```
$(function(){
    $("#commentForm").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: '.validationSummary'
    });
});
```

Change it to:

```
$("#commentForm").validate(function(){
    errorLabelContainer: '.validationSummary'
});
```

See this code snippet:

```js
$("#commentForm").validate(function() {
  errorLabelContainer: $('.validationSummary')
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

label.error {
  color: red;
}

p {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
    <div class="validationSummary"></div>
    <p>
      <label for="email">E-Mail*</label><br />
      <input id="email" name="email" size="25" class="required email" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="comment">Your comment*</label><br />
      <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="22" class="required"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: $("#commentForm").validate(function(){ - it is wrong code and it broke errorLabelContainer :( That is why all errors near their inputs.